# Cannot import Postgres into Spark with JDBC but displays Hive warning

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, jdbc, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to import my Postgres database into my [Kubernetes Spark setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419402/how-to-load-jar-package-such-as-jdbc-in-kubernetes-spark)

After running `kubectl exec zeppelin-controller-3i97t -it -- pyspark --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1209`, I attempt to connect to the database:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
url = 'jdbc:postgresql://PG_SERVER_IP/db_name'
properties = {
    "user": "PG_USER",
    "password": "PASSWORD",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}
df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=url, table='objects', properties=properties)
```

but `df` is not defined for me to use and there are warnings below regarding Hive. How can I circumvent this issue? Why is Hive even involved? Anyway to bypass it so that I can import the data into Spark as RDD or dataframe?

> WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in
>   metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so
>   recording the schema version 1.2.0 WARN ObjectStore:
>   Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
>   WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class
>   should not accessed in runtime.
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.(Hive.java:166)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Hive config file is not in conf directory.

Comment: I didn't realize that I needed a Hive config file. Which config directory (Spark's, Zeppelin's, Hive's) are you suggesting it be in? Thanks